# Group By the position of the fieldname(column) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a situation where in I have to concatenate two columns and group the selection based on the position of the field selected. Is this possible in SQL.

My sample code which doesn't execute. Here, GROUP BY 4 must group by the po_noRM

```
SELECT Table_A.Po_no, Table_A.rmcode, SUM(Table_A.weight) as recvqty,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(Table_A.po_no)) + LTRIM(RTRIM(MBStran.rmcode)) as po_noRM
FROM Table_A
GROUP BY 4
ORDER BY Table_A.Po_no
```

**EDITED**
All the data in Table_A is of type varchar(20)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: Are you asking this because you do not want to repeat the expression with LTRIM(...) + LTRIM()? Several ways to avoid that, but unlike order by, don't think group by allows the position number.

Comment: no joshp I am unable to group by po_noRM. so i was thinking of a way to group by the column position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever fields you include in the `SELECT` statement must either be in an aggregate function or must be used in a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT Table_A.Po_no, Table_A.rmcode, SUM(Table_A.weight) as recvqty,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(Table_A.po_no)) + LTRIM(RTRIM(MBStran.rmcode)) as po_noRM
FROM Table_A
GROUP BY Table_A.Po_no, Table_A.rmcode, LTRIM(RTRIM(Table_A.po_no)) + LTRIM(RTRIM(MBStran.rmcode))
ORDER BY Table_A.Po_no
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't like repeating complex expressions, you can use a subquery instead:

```
select Table_A.Po_no, Table_A.rmcode, SUM(Table_A.weight) as recvqty,
       po_noRM
from (SELECT Table_A.Po_no, Table_A.rmcode, 
             LTRIM(RTRIM(Table_A.po_no)) + LTRIM(RTRIM(Table_A.rmcode)) as po_noRM
      FROM Table_A
     ) T
group by po_noRM, Po_no, rmcode
ORDER BY 1 desc
```

This has no effect on performance.

I fixed the query to include all columns but the sum in the group b statement.  Also, another table was mentioned in the rtrim(ltrim()) statement.  I changed it to Table_A.

However, I suspect this query doesn't do what you really want (which is to reduce the number of rows being returned, since you are still grouping by the components of po_noRM).  This may be closer to what you want:

```
select Po_no_trim, rmcode_trim, SUM(Table_A.weight) as recvqty,
       (po_no_trim+rmcode_trim) as po_noRM
from (SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Table_A.po_no)) as po_no_trim,
             LTRIM(RTRIM(Table_A.rmcode)) as rmcode_trim, Table_A.weight
      FROM Table_A
     ) T
group by po_noRM_trim, Po_no_trim
ORDER BY 1 desc
```

Comment: they are using SQL server so you will need a `GROUP BY` on the subquery, if there is no `GROUP BY` this will not work

Comment: Why would you need a group by on the subquery? It's not doing any aggregation.

Comment: @SteveHomer it was doing an aggregate when the answer was first posted

Comment: @bluefeet - ah ok, thought I was missing something!

Comment: @GordonLinoff no problem, I was slightly confused as to why you had the aggregating subquery without the group by.  :)

Comment: Thanks very much for the solutions! Is there any difference between this solution(first part) and what @bluefeet suggested. Does this run faster when added some additional functionality? bluefeet solution worked.. this one looks same except that it has a subquery.. am i correct?